# Updating schematic symbol in Altium

Tags: schematics, altium

I'm trying to learn Altium and would like to know if someone can point me in the right direction here or if it's even possible to do this.

So I've created a 20 pin symbol on a .SchLib for an IC and then placed it on a schematic .SchDoc so I can build my circuit, nice and easy no issues here. I then unlock the pins and re-arrange them as I see fit for better readability, so far so good.

Then I noticed I wanted to make the rectangle surrounding the pins bigger, but can't figure how to edit the symbol's graphic within the .SchDoc schematic (or create a new instance with my preferences without disturbing the original) unless I go and edit it right on the .SchLib it was originally created. But if I go and edit the symbol on the .SchLib and then update the .SchDoc the pin arrangement I had done is gone.

I looked to see if maybe there is a way to lock the update so that the pins arrangement or something of that sort. In orcad capture I just update the symbol right on the schematic and it creates a new cached version without disturbing the original.

[image: Example or re-arranged pins, not Altium btw]

Comment: Can you show an example  of what kind of part it makes sense to re-arrange the pins on the schematic instead of just getting them right in the library?

Comment: @ThePhoton this is a thing that some designers do. It can make schematic management a pain for obvious reasons though.

Comment: I don't have Altium pulled up, but I would look and see what parameters show up in the Properties Inspector when you have a single pin selected. You might just be able to select the pins you want and change the pin length property there.

Comment: Why don't you edit the schlib symbol in your custom library? You can give it a different name. I don't think it's a good idea to edit instances of the symbol that way.

Comment: Edited original post to add an example. @Spehro Pefhany I think that might be the only and best way, just trying to see if there are other options.